# Word 2010: Using field codes in custom number lists

Tags: microsoft-word

what I'm trying to do is make a custom number list which not only gives the number in the list but also contains a reference to the heading it is under. This example shows how I want my numbered lists to look:

```
1. Heading One
1.1 Subheading One

    Numbered list
    Note 1.1 - 1: First point of paragraph 1.1
    Note 1.1 - 2: Second point of paragraph 1.1 

2. Heading Two
2.1 Subheading One

    Numbered list
    Note 2.1 - 1: First point of paragraph 2.1
    Note 2.1 - 2: Second point of paragraph 2.1
    Note 2.1 - 3: Third point of paragraph 2.1

2.2 Subheading Two

    Numbered list
    Note 2.2 - 1: First point of paragraph 2.2
    Note 2.2 - 2: Second point of paragraph 2.2
```

I know how to insert fields such as `{STYLEREF "Heading 2"}` and also how to "define new number format". What I can't figure out is how to combine the two. I would like everything before and including the colon to be part of the automatically created number in the list e.g. `Note 2.1 - 3:` = `Note {STYLEREF "Heading 2"} - 3:`.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi-level list and incorporate your Note 1.1 - 1:  as (say) the Level 3 numbering.

The first two levels would be linked to Heading 1 and Heading 2 respectively, then your Note paragraph style would be linked to the third level.

In the Enter formatting for number: textbox for this third level, you would type the word Note followed by inserting fields for the Level 1 and 2 numbering via the Include level number from dropdown box just below and to the right of the textbox.  The final number before your colon would be set using the Number style for this level: dropdown immediately below.

So you would have Note then space then field for level 1 numbering then full stop then field for level 2 numbering then space then dash then space, then you would select 1,2,3... from the Number style for this level dropdown below the textbox.